# Breadth-First Search heuristics to find solution to Water Jug Challenge

Tags: c++, tree, search, breadth-first-search, ai

I started learning AI recently. In AI, searches should be avoided and everything in AI is a search problem.

One of the easiest problem where we could use general AI search techniques is the [water jug problem](http://www.binding-time.co.uk/wiki/index.php/The_Water_Jugs_Problem) which states:

> You are given two jugs, a 4-gallon one and a 3-gallon one. Neither has any measuring markers on it. There is a tap that can be used to fill the jugs with water. How can you get exactly 2 gallons of water into the 4-gallon jug?

I solved it using the BFS technique:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector <pair<int,int> > newStatesSet(pair<int,int> state){
  //generating all possible states from a given initial state
  vector<pair<int,int> > newStates;
  if(state.first==0 && state.second==0){
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(3,0));
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(0,4));
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(3,4));
  }
  if(state.first!=0 && state.second==0){
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(state.first,4));
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(0,state.first));
    if(state.first<3){
      newStates.push_back(make_pair(3,0));
      newStates.push_back(make_pair(3,4));
    }
  }
  if(state.first==0 && state.second!=0){
    int transferQuantity;
    if(state.second>3)
      transferQuantity=3;
    else
      transferQuantity=state.second;
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(transferQuantity,state.second-transferQuantity));
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(3,state.second));
  }
  if(state.first!=0 && state.second!=0){
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(0,state.second));
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(state.first,0));
    if(state.second<4){
      int transferQuantity1=state.second+state.first;
      int transferQuantity2;
      if(transferQuantity1>4){
        transferQuantity2=transferQuantity1-4;
        transferQuantity1=4;
      }
      else
        transferQuantity2=0;
      newStates.push_back(make_pair(transferQuantity2,transferQuantity1));
    }
    if(state.first<3){
      int transferQuantity1=state.second+state.first;
      int transferQuantity2;
      if(transferQuantity1>3){
        transferQuantity2=transferQuantity1-3;
        transferQuantity1=3;
      }
      else
        transferQuantity2=0;
      newStates.push_back(make_pair(transferQuantity1,transferQuantity2));
    }
  }
  return newStates;
}

bool checkGoal(pair<int,int> x,int sum){
  if(x.second==sum)
    return true;
  return false;
}

void reverseTraversal(map <pair<int,int>,pair<int,int> > parent,pair<int,int> initialState,pair<int,int> goalState){
  if(initialState != goalState){
    reverseTraversal(parent,parent[initialState],goalState);
  }
  cout<<"("<<initialState.first<<","<<initialState.second<<")"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  //capacity (3,4)  
  //open list
  queue <pair<int,int> > Q;
  pair <int,int> parNode;
  //contains all the states
  map < pair<int,int> ,int > occured;
  //contains parent
  map < pair<int,int>,pair<int,int> > parent;

  Q.push(make_pair(0,0));
  while(Q.empty()!=true){
    parNode=Q.front();
    Q.pop();
    if(checkGoal(parNode,2))
      break;
    occured[parNode]++;
    vector <pair<int,int> > leafs = newStatesSet(parNode);
    for(int i=0;i<leafs.size();i++){
      if(occured[leafs[i]]==0){
        Q.push(leafs[i]);
        parent[leafs[i]]=parNode;
      }
    }
  }
  reverseTraversal(parent,parNode,make_pair(0,0));
}
```

What do you think is wrong with this code, and how can it be improved? What corner case have I overlooked, if any? How can I make it less complicated?

---

Improvements based on suggestion [can be found here](https://github.com/imrandomizer/common-programs/blob/master/WaterJugProblem.cpp)

Comment: Not using C++ for AI work would be a good start. There are languages specifically designed for writing AI that provide semantics that are more natural to express these problems.

Comment: One interesting change would be to show all equally good solutions (e.g., using your notation: (0, 0), (0, 4), (3, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 4), (3, 2) uses the same number of steps).

Comment: @LokiAstari normally i would use Python to write these programs, but because of having some experience in c++ i knew this particular problem/solution would be easier to portray in c++ than in python at-least for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the function that computes new states could be simplified in this way:

```
vector <pair<int,int> > newStatesSet(pair<int,int> state){
  //generating all possible states from a given initial state
  vector<pair<int,int> > newStates;

  if (state.first < 3) {
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(3, state.second));
  }
  if (state.second < 4) {
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(state.first, 4));
  }
  if (state.first > 0) {
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(0, state.second));
  }
  if (state.second > 0) {
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(state.first, 0));
  }
  if (state.second > 0 && state.first < 3) {
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(std::min(3, state.first + state.second),
                        std::max(state.second - (3 - state.first), 0)));
  }
  if (state.first > 0 && state.second < 4) {
    newStates.push_back(make_pair(std::max(state.first - (4 - state.second), 0),
                        std::min(4, state.second + state.first)));
  }

  return newStates;
}
```

Note that with this function a new state is generated from the previous state by considering a single operation. So, for instance, from the state (0, 0) it produces (3, 0) and (0, 4), but not (3, 4) (which will be generated later) as in your function. I think that this reflect more correctly the idea that each state is derived from the previous one with a single step.

Comment: Yes in my function going to state (3,4) directly from (0,0) is wrong as we are only allowed to do one operation each step. Thanks for pointing that out and for this succinct version of newStatesSet.

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked your code for correct output, just for coding-related issues. Here are some comments.

**Avoid using std**

- Nix `using namespace std`. Read up on the rationale [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

**Pre-allocate vector size when you know roughly how large it will be**

- Rather than rushing a number of `push_back` operations when you know how many, or roughly how many, you will need, preallocate the vector first. In `newStatesSet` you know the size you will make `vector newStates` so you should call `reserve` after the declaration and before you start your `push_backs`. Otherwise the vector likely has to relocate after the first 2 pushes (`std::vector` tends to double each time memory must be reallocated, so you'll usually go from 2 to 4 to 8 and so on....)

**Brevity**

- You can shorten `checkGoal` like so:

  `bool checkGoal(pair<int,int> x,int sum){
    return (x.second==sum);
  }`

  Also consider restructuring the arguments to take `x.second` directly as an
  `int` value parameter rather than unnecessarily passing the whole `pair`. Both
  these adjustments should improve performance as well as code readability.

**Avoid side effects**

- `reverseTraversal` is a void that makes some changes to state *and also* prints something out. You generally want to do one or the other in a function. It's best not to have print statements scattered throughout functions.

---

**Additional Possible improvements:**

**Reference to const can be better than passing by value**

- Since you don't seem to manipulate your input parameter in `newStatesSet`, you should consider passing it by [reference to const rather than by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204556/pass-by-value-or-const-reference-to-function). I may be wrong that this would improve performance since a `pair` of `ints` shouldn't be that large, but you can benchmark to confirm.

**Try making local copies of oft-used class members**

- Looking at `newStatesSet`, I think you might consider making a local variable copy of `state.first` and `state.second` since you access them often. Whether this improves performance is [compiler dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269874/performance-difference-between-accessing-local-and-class-member-variables).

Comment: reverseTraversal is only for printing the final answer after a final traversal it does not make any changes to states **  is a void that makes some changes to state **,  Am i missing something here?